# Form action won't call login function

Tags: php, authentication

I have an HTML login form whose action sends to another PHP file where there is a function that is supposed to login user on to the site. When submited form leads to that php file but it shows an empty page like it doesn't trigger that function. I put echo and die on top of the function but still, nothing happens.

Also when I echo something outside of function it displays what I entered in echo, so it calls the right file just it won't load function. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

**login.php**

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            login_function();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/login_assets/css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/login_assets/css/media.css">
        <script src="/login_assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/login_assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="clear hBlack">
            <div class="jLogo"><a href="/"><img src="/login_assets/images/logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
        </header>
        <div class="logArea clear">
            <form action="custom_functions.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                <div class="logbox">
                    <div class="box clear">
                        <h2>Members Area</h2>
                        <div class="logTypes">
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="logtextbox" placeholder="Username or email">
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $username_error;  ?></span>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="logtextbox" placeholder="Password"><br>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $password_error;  ?></span>
                            <!-- <input type="text" name="captcha" class="logtextbox" placeholder="Enter the code shown below"><br>
                            <img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="captcha.php">
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $captcha_error;  ?></span> -->
                            <div style="text-align: center">Remember my login: <input name="remember" type="checkbox"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="logBtn" name="submit"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <footer class="clear">
            <p class="fNav"><a href="/">Home</a><span>|</span>
                <a href="/">Log Out</a>
            </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**custom_functions.php**

```
<?php
    //echo "AAAAAAAAA";

    function validation($form_data)
    {
        $form_data = trim(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($form_data)) );
        return $form_data;
    }
    function login_function() {
        //echo "AAAAAAAAAA";
        //die('!');
        session_start();
        require 'connection.php';
        $username_error = "";
        $password_error = "";
        //$captcha_error = "";
        $v_username = $_POST['username'];
        $v_password = $_POST['password'];
        //$v_captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
        $username = validation($v_username);
        $password = validation($v_password);
        //$captcha = validation($v_captcha);
        $remember = isset($_POST['remember']);
        if (empty($username)) {
            $username_error = "<p>Please enter your username!</p>";
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            $password_error = "<p>Please enter your password!</p>";
        }
        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM member_auth WHERE username = :username";
            //$sql = "SELECT * FROM member_auth LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

            $stmt->execute();

            $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $cryptpass = $user['cryptpass'];

            if($user === false){
                $username_error = "<p>User doesn't exist</p>";
            } elseif ($user) {
                $newPass = crypt($password, $cryptpass);
                if ($cryptpass == $newPass) {
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    if ($remember == "on") {
                        setcookie("remember", $username, time()+3600);
                    }
                    header('Location: login_success.php');
                } else {
                    $password_error = "<p>Password is not correct!</p>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Put both filess in same folder. and check it.

Comment: Your action is on `custom_function.php`, and you call it from the same page so change your action or change the location of if condition

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Both files are in the same folder

Comment: Your form just calls `custom_functions.php`, which declares two functions but never actually runs any of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your condition from same page to `custom_functions.php`

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        login_function();
    }
}
```

or

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. What a stupid mistake. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you call login function in the login page and define the function in custom.php page so it does not find any function in this file put your code in the same function and it will work.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    login_function();
}}
```